# Ranking via ORDER based on field, for multiple groups in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL table which I'm trying to provide ranks for based on groups which I'm created depending on specific columns.

My table Teams looks something like this.

| Team | Wins | Division |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team A | 2 | One |
| Team B | 1 | One |
| Team C | 4 | Two |
| Team D | 5 | Three |
| Team E | 7 | Four |
| Team F | 9 | Four |
| Team G | 6 | Four |

What I want to do, is give a rank to each team, based on it's wins, but the rank to be related to the division. So the table would look something like this.

| Team | Wins | Division | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Team A | 2 | One | 1 |
| Team B | 1 | One | 2 |
| Team C | 4 | Two | 1 |
| Team D | 5 | Three | 1 |
| Team E | 7 | Four | 2 |
| Team F | 9 | Four | 1 |
| Team G | 6 | Four | 3 |

So basically, give a rank to each team for it's specific division, and that rank is based on the wins for each team.

The way I've currently approached it, is to break up the table into multiple divisons, add the ranking and then combine those through a union.

As follows

```
with one as (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY wins DESC) AS rank
  FROM TEAMS
  WHERE TEAMS.Division="One"
),
two as (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY wins DESC) AS rank
  FROM TEAMS
  WHERE TEAMS.Division="Two"
),
three as (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY wins DESC) AS rank
  FROM TEAMS
  WHERE TEAMS.Division="Three"
),
four as (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY wins DESC) AS rank
  FROM TEAMS
  WHERE TEAMS.Division="Four"
),
combined_tables as (
  SELECT * FROM one
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM two
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM three
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM four
)
SELECT * FROM combined_tables
```

With this method, I do get my desired outcome. However, I feel as if as I add more divisions, this query becomes very long.

Are there any simpler/better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `RANK` along with a `PARTITION BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT Team, Wins, Division,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Division ORDER BY Wins DESC) "Rank"
FROM TEAMS;
```

Comment: Ah, PARTITION was what I was looking for. That worked, thank you so much!